# The continuous equation of the line

Tags: geometry

I've got 2 lines :

$$
r:\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
y=2x+3 \\ 
z=2x-2
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
and
$$
s:\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x-y+z=0 \\ 
x-y+2=0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
I have to write the continuous equations of those lines. I mean, I have to write them on this form: $\frac{x-x_1}{v_1}=\frac{x-x_2}{v_2}=\frac{x-x_3}{v_3}$, being $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ a pont of the line and $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ the direction vector of the line.

---

I have done the line r:

$
r:\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x=\lambda \\ 
y=2\lambda+3 \\
z=2\lambda-2
\end{array}
\right. 
$

$\Rightarrow  r: x=\frac{y-3}{2}=\frac{z+2}{2}$

---

But how can I do the same with the line s?

Is the s line ok?

Comment: @FShrike They both are lines. $s$ is a line in the plane at $z=2$

Comment: yes, you are right @Andrei , both are lines. But how can I write the continuous equation of s? Maybe $z=2, y=\lambda, x=\lambda -2$???

Comment: @Andrei I was reading each line of equations as a separate thing : ) not as information coupled together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We first find the direction vector of $s$. In your case $s$ is given as an intersection of two planes, and the vector product of the normal vectors of the two plane is exactly the direction vector. In general if:
$$
r:\begin{cases} ax+by+cz +d =0 \\
ex+fy+gz+h = 0\end{cases} = \begin{cases}\pi_1 \\
\pi_2\end{cases} 
$$
where $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are the two planes and $r$ their intersection. Then:
$\vec{v} = (a,b,c)\times(e,f,g)$ is a direction vector for $r$. Let's apply this formula in your case:

$$
\vec{v}_s = (1,-1,1)\times(1,-1,0)= \begin{vmatrix}
\vec{i} & \vec{j} & \vec{k}\\
1 & -1 & 1\\
1 & -1 & 0
\end{vmatrix} = (1,1,0)
$$
and since $(1,3,2)\in s$, then its parametric equations are:
$$
s:\begin{cases}x = 1+\lambda \\
y = 3+\lambda \\
z = 2\end{cases}; \lambda\in\mathbb{R}
$$
And finally:
$$
\implies s: x-1 = y-3 \mbox{ in the plane $z = 2$}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The form you want to write works only if $v_i\ne 0$ for all components. An equivalent way, that works afor all cases is $$(x,y,z)=(x_0,y_0,z_0)+\lambda(v_x, v_y, v_z)$$
So for $s$, by subtracting the two equation you get $z=2$. Since this is constant, it means $v_z=0$. Then for $$x-y+2=0$$ choose $x=\lambda$. Therefore $y=\lambda+2$. With that,
$$(x,y,z)=(0,2,2)+\lambda(1,1,0)$$